# Is there a mistake in Hartshorne Proposition II.6.6?

Tags: commutative-algebra

This is Proposition II.6.6 in Hartshorne. We assume that $X$ is a Noetherian, integral, and separated scheme which is regular in codimension 1, i.e. every local ring of dimension one is regular.

For this question, I am solely interested in the Type I points, namely, points $x \in X \times \mathbf{A}^1$ whose closures are of codimension one and under the image of the projection map to $X$, is another point $y$ of codimension one. Hartshorne claims

> $x$ is the generic point of $\pi ^{-1} (y)$. Its local ring $\mathcal{O}_x \cong \mathcal{O}_y[t] _{\mathfrak m_y}.$

However, I think there is a mistake here, I believe the correct statement here is $\mathcal{O}_x \cong \mathcal{O}_y[t] _{\mathfrak m_y[t]}$, since we have the following conclusion that could be proved easily.

Let $B$ be a domain and $\mathfrak p$ a prime ideal of $B$, then we have $B[t]_{\mathfrak p[t]}\cong B_\mathfrak p[t]_{\mathfrak pB_{\mathfrak p}[t]}.$

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You should know by now that you need to provide *context*.

Comment: I have corrected my question.

Comment: That's much better. Thank you.